# Attaching dynamic Line Renderer to GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've created a (3D)-canvas which includes a list. The canvas is located in the world space. It also faces to the camera all the time when it's activated by selecting a GameObject. Now I'd like the add a dynamic Line Renderer between the upper left corner of the canvas and the point of the RaycastHit / selected object (see sketch). The position of the LR on the GO-side should be static, the LR on the list-side should be dynamic. Thus, it should stay attached at the corner even the canvas starts rotating in all axis (x,y,z).

[image: sketch]

I already stuck at the positioning of the LR on the list-side. I don't get the corner-coordinates to attach the LR there. I've already tried the bounds-method and some others but I'm not getting ahead. My code so far:

```
//GUI elements
public Canvas canvas_list;
public GameObject content_list;

LineRenderer lr_list;

// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{
    Setup_LR();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{
    // Canvas facing to the camera
    canvas_list.transform.rotation = ar_camera.transform.rotation;

    // LineRenderer is always attachted to canvas (Part 1)
    lr_list.SetPosition(1, new Vector3(canvas_list.GetComponent<Collider>().bounds.min.x, canvas_list.GetComponent<Collider>().bounds.max.y, canvas_list.GetComponent<Collider>().bounds.min.z));

    // Selecting objects
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Selecting_Objects();
    }
}

void Selecting_Objects()
{
    raycastHit = new RaycastHit();   

    if (Physics.Raycast(ar_camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), out raycastHit))
    {
        if (!EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
        {
            GameObject selected_object = raycastHit.collider.gameObject;

            // LineRenderer is always attachted to building component (Part 2) - avoids that the line renderer gets attached to GUI element
            lr_list.SetPosition(0, raycastHit.point);
        }
    }
}


void Setup_LR()
{
    canvas_list.transform.gameObject.AddComponent<BoxCollider>();

    lr_list = new GameObject().AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
    lr_list.material.color = Color.red;
    lr_list.startWidth = 0.01f;
    lr_list.endWidth = 0.01f;
}
```

That's how it looks now:
[image]
Thanks!

Comment: attach a screenshot of the results from your code